# How can I overcome the Errno 21 error in Python while creating a new dataset from a corpus?

Tags: python, text, nltk, decision-tree, tf-idf

Basically, I have a .txt corpus that I compiled from the Internet. To use some other analysis tools (DecisionTreeClassifier, Bar Plots, TFiD, etc.), I am trying to convert this corpus into a dataset by using a code I found on the Internet (for more explanation: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/analyzing-documents-with-tfidf)

I vectorized my corpus into arrays:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.65, min_df=1, use_idf=True, norm=None)
doc1= vectorizer.fit_transform(doc1withoutskipwords)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=.65, min_df=1, use_idf=True, norm=None)
doc2= vectorizer.fit_transform(doc2withoutskipwords)

doctr1 = doc1toarray()
len(doctr1)

doctr2 = doc2.toarray()
len(doctr2)

Path("myname/nltk_data/tf_idf_output").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
output_filenames = [str(txt_file).replace(".txt", ".csv").replace("txt/", "tf_idf_output/") for txt_file in doc1withoutskipwords]
for counter, doc in enumerate(poltrans):
    tf_idf_tuples = list(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), doc))    
    one_doc_as_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(tf_idf_tuples, columns=['term', 'score']).sort_values(by='score', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    one_doc_as_df.to_csv(output_filenames[counter])
```

Then I received this error: IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'documents'

I was able to run the Path and output_filenames line of codes separately and they worked. I have tf_id_output file at the place I want. But, I cannot solve the rest of it.

I am an extremely novice Python coder so I am very confused.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include a minimal reproducible example. Currently this needs a lot more detail: what is `poltrans`? Is this using the `TfidfVectorizer` from scikit-learn, etc.?

Comment: Most likely the `IsADirectoryError` is being raised because this tries to write to a directory as if it were a file, rather than writing to a new file. Adding something to the end of each string in `output_filenames` might fix this.